# Proving that E (set of even integers) is equal to F (sum of two odd integers)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Define E to be the set of even integers; E = {$x$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$ :  $x$ = 2$k$, where $k$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$}.

Define F to be the set of integers that can be expressed as the sum of two odd integers such that

$F   =  \{y  $$\in$  $\mathbb{Z}$ : y  = a  +  b,  where  $a$ = $2k_1$ +  1 and $b$ = $2k_2 +1\}$.

Prove E = F.

My attempt: If $x$ = 2$k$ is even $a$ and $b$ can be written as a = $2k_1$, b = $2k_2$. so $a + b$ = $2k_1 + 2k_2 + 2$ = 2($k_1 + k_2$ + 1) which is even.

Comment: Every number $n$ is equal to $(n-1) + 1$.

Answer (score 2):

$F \subset E$ is trivial, as sum of two odd numbers is even.

For the second direction, note, that each number $n$ is a sum of $n-1$ and $1$, which in case of an even $n$ are both odd.